# SQL, build a query using data provided in the query itself

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

For experimental purposes only.

I would like to build a query but not querying data extracted for any table but querying data provided in the query it self. Like:

```
select numbers.* from (1, 2, 3) as numbers;
```

or

```
select numbers.* from (field1 = 1, field2 = 2, field3 = 3) as numbers;
```

so I can do things like

```
select 
  numbers.* 
from (field1 = 1, field2 = 2, field3 = 3) as numbers 
where numbers.field1 > 1;
```

If the solution is specific for a database engine could be interesting too.

Comment: You could do `SELECT numbers.* FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, 3 AS c UNION SELECT 4, 5, 6) AS numbers`

Comment: @scragar can you please create an answer with your solution? it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted the values to be on separate rows instead of three fields of the same row, the method is the same, just one row per value linked with a `union all`.

```
select *
from(
    select 1 as FieldName union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all -- we could continue this for a long time
    select 5 -- the end
) as x;

select numbers.*
from(
    select 1 ,2, 3 
    union select 3, 4, 5
    union select 6, 7, 8
    union select 9, 10, 11 -- we could continue this for a long time
    union select 12, 13, 14 -- the end
) as numbers;
```

This works with MySQL *and* Postgres (and most others as well).

[Edit] Use `union all` rather than just `union` as you do not need to remove duplicates from a list of constants. Give the field(s) in the first `select` a meaningful name. Otherwise, you can't specify a specific field later on: `where x.FieldName = 3`.

If you don't provide meaningful names for the fields (as in the second example), the system (at least MySQL where this was tested) will assign the name "1" for the first field, "2" as the second and so on. So, if you want to specify one of the fields, you have to write expressions like this:

```
where numbers.1 = 3
```

Comment: Accepted because it is the most clear answer and not engine specific.

Comment: No, the ALL is necessary. As this is a list of constants, it is highly unlikely that any duplicates will exist, unless they are intentional. If there are no duplicates, it is a waste of cycles for the system to do the fruitless sorting and deduping and if they are intentional then you certainly don't want those duplications removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `values` row constructor:

```
select *
from (values (1),(2),(3)) as numbers(nr);
```

or using a CTE.

```
with numbers (nr) as (
   values (1),(2),(3)
)
select * 
from numbers
where nr > 2;
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that you also taggeg your question with `mysql`: the above will not work with MySQL, only with Postgres (and a few other DBMS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery without table like so:

```
SELECT
    numbers.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS a,
        2 AS b,
        3 AS c
    UNION
    SELECT
        4,
        5,
        6
) AS numbers
WHERE
    numbers.a > 1
```

If you like queries to always have a table referenced there is a Psuedo table that always has 1 row and no columns called `DUAL`, you can use it like so:

```
SELECT
    numbers.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS a,
        2 AS b,
        3 AS c
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
        4,
        5,
        6
    FROM
        DUAL
) AS numbers
WHERE
    numbers.a > 1
```